# How do I pass a link through ViewData in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

still pretty new to MVC and its logic

I have a controller that has something that looks like

```
if (test1 != test2)
{
    ViewData["Return"] = "<a href =\ "http://alpha.pm.com" +">Home</a>";
    return View()
}
```

and I'd like to be able for the view to take this ViewData in, and display a button for a link.

I'm having a bit of trouble with this, so any recommendations or other options would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, I was told that I shouldn't use any logic in the View, so what I currently have is just

```
 @html.encode(ViewData["Return"])
```

but this just displays text.. so I'm unsure how to approach this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you shouldn't have logic in the view, you also shouldn't have view (eg, HTML) in the controller.

You should pass the URL in the controller, and assemble the tag in the view:

```
@if (ViewData["Return"] != null) {
    <a href="@ViewData["Return"]>Home</a>
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is, I was told to have no 'if' statements within the view, which is my main issue at the moment :/

Comment: @user2094139: You were told incorrectly.  There is nothing wrong with `if` statements that check flags from the controller.  The problem is `if` statements that contain actual business logic.

Comment: In other words, `if (test1 != test2)` does not belong in a view, but `if (Model.ShouldIncludeThingy)` does.